# Understanding a proof in a random walk on a random graph journal paper

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem 2 part (i) (in page 4) of this [paper.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.01999.pdf) This theorem is about the rate of convergence in total variation distance of a Markov chain on a random graph.

Without writing details about all the parameters, the statement of the theorem is:

> Let $G$ be a random graph with degree distribution $(p_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$. Let $n$ be the number of vertices of $G$. Let $P$ be the transition matrix of a Markov chain on $G$. Let $d_{\rm{TV}}^x(t):= \|P^t(x,\cdot)-\pi\|_{\rm{TV}}$ be the total-variation distance of the distribution of the walk started from a fixed vertex $x$ from the stationary distribution of the Markov chain $\pi$ after $t$ steps. Then with high probability on the event that $v_1$ is in the largest component of $G$,
> $$d_{\rm{TV}}^{v_1}(t^\star-w_n)>1-\varepsilon, d_{\rm{TV}}^{v_1}(t^\star+w_n)<\varepsilon$$
> I am trying to understand the proof of the upper bound: $d_{\rm{TV}}^{v_1}(t^\star+w_n)<\varepsilon$ which is in page 18. Essentially, the statement means that the total-variation distance at time $t^{\star}+w_n$ is small with high-probability.

**Explanation of the proof:** In the proof (in page 18), they construct the graph $G'$ from $G$ by contracting every path of length $R:=c\log\log n$ to a single vertex. Let $U=V(G)\setminus V(G')$, where $V(G),V(G')$ are the vertices in $G,G'$ respectively. The proof is essentially split into two parts. The first part proves (3.21) which I understand:
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{v\in V}\mathbb{P}_v(\mathcal{B}_{U,\log^2 n})=o(1) \,.$$
which basically means that the probability that the Markov chain on $G$ traversing vertices of $U$ until time $\log^2 n$ is small.

The second part (bottom of page 18) says $G'$ is an expander with high probability and that the spectral gap of $G'$ is greater than $c/R^2$ for some constant $c>0$. I understand this part, too.

**Part of the proof I don't understand:** Finally, in page 19, the paper says the above two parts *establishes the following:*

There exists a constant $\gamma>0$ such that with probability at least $1-\varepsilon-o(1)$, $d_{\rm{TV}}^{v_1}(t^\star + \gamma w_n')<\varepsilon$.

I am not at all sure how the above two parts immediately establish the above statement. Any ideas? Thanks.